# How to control the player by using four buttons up,down,right,left in cocos2d game for ios?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How to control the player by using four buttons up,down,right,left in cocos2d game for ios
i want to control the player by using four buttons

Comment: previously i used joystick but in that it moves in all directions but i want only four directions and am new to cocos2d game

Comment: try to read the documentation and start programming first.

Comment: ok U have any idea about this?

Comment: Why dont you look up a tutorial on `Google` instead of asking us to do it for you? Nobody here is going to type out a whole tutorial in an answer for you, coding involves some research, which isnt that difficult, especially when this topic is covered quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

First explain what is the current scenario and what is happening ??? Like your player is continuously moving or what?

Now, TO your answer, There will be 4 buttons, ok?

You will touch any of them and with respect to that you just have to change either x position of player or y position of the player. And if you want to continuously move your player on one touch,then you have to implement code which will identify that your button is pressed for some finite time and on the basis of that you can move your player.